# I am in Israel after 90 days without a visa, can I get in trouble for this?

Tags: visas, israel

Without judgement, please, I need help. I am in Israel at the moment and have been here for longer than 90 days, surpassing my allowed 90 day allowance. Am I going to get in trouble when I go to get my visa? I am a student and I have been here almost four months now... I am afraid to go get my visa because I'm overdue. Will they kick me out? Will I be okay? I don't know how much they enforce the 90 day rule.

Comment: Why does this have the [tag:usa] tag?

Comment: And what kind of visa are you trying to get?  Are you hoping to stay in Israel (for what purpose and how long?) or are you just trying to leave without further trouble?  If your goal is to stay for an extended period, then http://expatriates.stackexchange.com might offer more useful advice, but I suspect much of it will come down to "find a good immigration lawyer".

Answer (score 2):

This page gives [some information on Israel visas](http://www.lonelyplanet.com/israel-and-the-palestinian-territories/practical-information/visas).

By comparison with other countries, Israel seems to be fairly laid-back about overstays.

> Note that overstaying your allotted time elicits a fine of 135NIS per month – this can be sorted out at Ministry of the Interior offices or Ben-Gurion airport, but not at land borders. Travellers who overstay by just a few days report no hassles or fines.

However this doesn't necessarily mean it won't impact your actual visa. If you overstayed one time, they might think you will overstay again. I can't think of any reason why waiting would make this better - if your visa is ready for collection, go get it sorted out now.